# How can I retain an old version of wolframscript during an upgrade?

Tags: scripting, installation

During the process of upgrading Mathematica to a newer version, we are presented with the choice of retaining or uninstalling an older version. But it seems that this choice does not extend to WolframScript. In fact, while there are multiple directories for Mathematica on the computer, there is only one directory for WolframScript:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\WolframResearch\Mathematica\13.1
C:\ProgramFiles\WolframResearch\Mathematica\13.2

C:\ProgramFiles\WolframResearch\WolframScript\wolframscript.exe
```

I tend to run most of my Wolfram Language code from the command line, and I would like to ensure that everything is running correctly before I delete an older version. Is there an official, recommended way to retain the old version of `wolframscript.exe` (without manually copying over the file and potentially running into problems with relative paths, etc.)

Comment: When I install `Mathematica` I always immediately rename it to include the version number. Consequently, when I subsequently install a newer version there is never a name conflict and I never deal with the option of retaining or uninstalling. You could try that approach with `WolframScript`

Comment: I recommend using the tool "Module" that can be found at https://modules.sourceforge.net/. This tool sets environment information for every application. For instance, to load a different version of WoflramScript, one need just to execute "module load math/wolframscript/13.0", for instance. To unload, one has to invoke "module unload math/wolframscript/13.0".